# How can change the behavior of Devexpress to produce the my expectation view instead of default view

Tags: winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

Normally, when you run the Devexpress WinForm project, you will see the objects as predetermined. Like this:

[image: category]

[image: worktime]

How can I change the behavior of DevExpress?
How can I apply TreeList instead of the default list from DevExpress?
(Or in general, change the presentation of data corresponding to my wishes)

My project structure:

[image: my project structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see you're talking about the XAF ListView's customization.
In order to accomplish the hierarchical representation, I suggest you review the guide [Tree List Editors (Organize Hierarchical Data)](https://docs.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/112841/application-shell-and-base-infrasctructure/tree-list-editors-module) and the example [How to Use Tree List Editors to Display List Views](https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/XAF_how-to-use-tree-list-editors-to-display-list-views-e1125).

In short, to display data in a tree-like structure, the [ITreeNode](https://docs.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/DevExpress.Persistent.Base.General.ITreeNode) interface should be implemented in the appropriate business classes.